# React dependencies broken in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am getting the following error in IE11 `Assignment to read only properties is not allowed in strict mode`. After digging in it looks like the bug is inside the source code for ReactCSSTransitionGroup. The component renders fine in other browsers. Thoughts on what it could be?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The above might the be the limitation of the library; I have not investigated about this in detail, but to me it seems more around the rendering/interpreting engine behaviour.

I had got the same error within my code but it was with the how IE treat the elements rendering. The above line of code tries to add the `className` to the existing element. But, in IE the some elements are interpreted as read-only and thus the class assignment code will throw a error; In my case it was trying to set the `className` to SVG element which was not allowed in IE. Thus, I have to wrap my element into `<div>` and then everything worked fine.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This helped me out, was not working in IE11 until I wrapped my div that had dynamic classes with another div... weird!